# Supporting Like without using 35MB to do it?

Tags: facebook, ios8

I've been asked to incorporate a Like button into our iOS app. I downloaded the FB toolkit, and found that it's 35MB. That's seven times larger than our app. So...

1) is there a way to cut down this size?

2) is the another way to incorporate Like that's less expensive? I've seen some ways to do it that require login, perhaps there's another solution too?

Comment: Just because the download is 35 MB doesn't mean your app will be 35 MB bigger when you add the like button

Comment: The download is about 44 MB.

Comment: Still doesn't matter. It will not be 44 MB or 35 MB bigger